# How do I read the value of a cookie in the Play-Framework with Scala?

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework

How can I read the value of a cookie in my controller in the Play-Framework with Scala?

In my controller I have this:

```
println(Http.Request.current().headers.get("cookie"))
```

And the output is this:

```
[csrftoken=011d7cfe84915ee9897c8c6079d49d5a; test=value]
```

And I'm hoping there is a better way of accessing the value of "test" other than parsing the string.. ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can access the cookie using the `cookie` object on the HTTP Request, rather than getting it in raw format from the header. Look at the API [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.1/play/mvc/Http.Request.html) for more info.

You should be able to just do:

`Http.Request.current().cookies.get("test")`

Comment: Is this different to `request.cookies.get("test")` or is it the same thing?

Comment: its almost the same. Except, if you don't have access to the request object, you can get it by using `Http.Request.current()`. The OP did not specify he had access to the request object, so it was safer to continue with the same syntax he used.

Comment: In Play + Scala I don't think I have a request object in-scope by default. @Codemwnci's answer worked great; Thank you!

Comment: @pyrony: Yes you have, I use the code in the comment I posted. And I use Scala + Play.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookie value in scala template using 
    @request.cookies.get("email").value.

If you want to check its not null,
    @if(request.cookies.get("email") != null) {}

Answer (score 1):

I am using Play 2.6.19 with Scala and I fetch as below;

```
val leadToken = request.cookies.get("lead_token") match {
 case Some(cookie) => cookie.value
 case None => ""
}
```